Literature containing basic knowledge of homogeneous functions
Let $D$ be a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function of two variables. For all $(x,y)\in D$ and $t>0$ such that $(tx,ty)\in D$, if the equality $f(tx,ty)=t^\alpha f(x,y)$ is valid for some real number $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, then we call $f$ a homogeneous function of order $\alpha$ on $D$.
Could you please recommend literature containing basic knowledge of the above-defined homogeneous functions for me to cite in a manuscript? Thank you very much!

The most convenient source of information on homogeneous functions is Wikipedia; if that is not satisfactory as a source, you could cite:
J.P. Lewis, Homogeneous Functions and Euler’s Theorem. In: An Introduction to Mathematics (Palgrave Macmillan, London, 1969).

Thank you very much for your answer, Dr. Carlo Beenakker

Is the following baisc property contains in the reference by Lewis?
Let $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable homogeneous function of order $n$. Then $\partial_1f$ and $\partial_2f$ are homogeneous functions of order $n-1$ and
$$
x\partial_1f(x,y)+y\partial_2f(x,y)=n f(x,y).
$$
In particular, if $n=1$ and $f$ is twice differentiable on $D$, then
\begin{align*}
x\partial_1f(x,y)+y\partial_2f(x,y) &=f(x,y),\
x\partial_1^2f(x,y)+y\partial_1\partial_2f(x,y) &=0,\
x\partial_1\partial_2f(x,y)+y\partial_2^2f(x,y) &=0.
\end{align*}

I will email you a copy.

I received your e-mail. Thank you a lot.

The above differential properties are contained in the paper by Lewis. But I don't find the following integral property in it: Let $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ be a homogeneous function of order $n$ and let $[0,x]\times [0,y]\subseteq D$. If $u\mapsto f(u,y)$ is integrable on $[0,x]$ (or $v\mapsto f(x,v)$ is integrable on $[0,y]$, respectively), then the function $x\mapsto\int_0^{x}f(u,y)\operatorname{d}!u$ (or the function $x\mapsto\int_0^{y}f(x,v)\operatorname{d}!v$, respectively) is a homogeneous function of order $n+1$.
